# devise error: Log in : Invalid email or password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is the bug:

```
Started GET "/javascripts/vendor/custom.modernizr.js" for ::1 at 2016-04-09 12:42:41 +0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"):
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
```

I create a user index about some user base info.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user
  before_action :owned_user, only: [:edit, :update]



  def index
      @user = User.all
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
        flash[:success] = 'Your profile has been updated.'
        redirect_to user_path(@user.name)
    else
        @user.errors.full_messages
        flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages
        render :edit
    end
  end




  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :avatar)
  end

  def owned_user
    unless current_user == @user
        flash[:alert] = "That profile doesn't belong to you!"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])
  end   


end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 16 }

end
```

about views/devise , I have not change anything.
This is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :topics
  devise_for :users
  resources :nodes

  root 'topics#index'

  get ':name', to: 'users#index', as: :users
  get ':name/edit', to: 'users#edit', as: :edit_user
  patch ':name/edit', to: 'users#update', as: :update_user

end
```

This is routes:

```
 new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)  devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)  devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format) devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET   /users/password/edit(.:format)devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)  devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)  devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)       devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format) devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)   devise/registrations#edit
                     PATCH  /users(.:format)       devise/registrations#update
                     PUT    /users(.:format)       devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)      devise/registrations#destroy

               users GET    /:name(.:format)               users#index
           edit_user GET    /:name/edit(.:format)          users#edit
         update_user PATCH  /:name/edit(.:format)          users#update
```

Thank you to help me , I am tired to solve devise. I am new , expect devise, Is there any Gem better to login/logout?

Answer (score 1):

I think your controller's routes & devise's routes may be conflicting. Try creating another controller with a different name such as Admin::UsersController.

Create a file in /app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb and try the code below.

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @user], notice: 'User is created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_without_password(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @user], notice: 'User is updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_users_url, notice: 'User is destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

And of course in your routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks , That's helped me another things, I will try it again.